# How to run script automatically on boot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opensuse

I have a python script that monitors USB ports (checks which devices are connected). The script performs some scraping and displays a desktop notification. I would like it to run automatically on every boot. This is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import glib
import re
import subprocess
import requests
import bs4
import datetime
import sys
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyudev import Context, Monitor
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def demote():
    def result():
        os.setgid(100)
        os.setuid(1000)
    return result

def inotify(title, message):
    subprocess.call(['notify-send', '{}\n'.format(title), '{0}\n'.format(message)], preexec_fn=demote())
    #os.system('notify-send ' + title + ' ' + message)

def get_network_data(tout):
    """Scrapes balance data from ISP website."""

    if tout is not None:
        try:
        # Do some scraping
            if data_found:
                full_msg = '{0}\n{1}'.format(my_balance.capitalize(), airtime_balance.capitalize())
                inotify('My Balance', full_msg)
                #subprocess.call(['notify-send', 'My Balance', '\n{0}\n{1}'.format(my_balance.capitalize(), airtime_balance.capitalize())], preexec_fn=demote())

            else:
                print('Could not retrieve data from page...')
                full_msg = '{0}'.format('Error: Could not retrieve data from page.')
                inotify('My Balance', full_msg)
                #subprocess.call(['notify-send', 'My Balance', '\n{0}'.format('Error: Could not retrieve data from page.')], preexec_fn=demote())

        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('Could not locate element...')
            full_msg = '{0}'.format('Error: Could not locate element - acc.')
            inotify('My Balance', full_msg)
            #subprocess.call(['notify-send', 'iMonitor:get_network_data', '\n{0}'.format('Error: Could not locate element - acc.')], preexec_fn=demote())

    else:
        print('Could not find USB device...')
        full_msg = '\n{0}'.format('Error: Could not find USB device.')
        inotify('My Balance', full_msg)
        #subprocess.call(['notify-send', 'iMonitor', '\n{0}'.format('Error: Could not find USB device.')], preexec_fn=demote())

def identify_phone(observer, device):
    """Identifies if specific USB device (phone) is connected (tethered)."""

    global last_updated, initial_search, msg_count

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_diff = current_time - last_updated

    if (time_diff.seconds > 300) or initial_search:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.25)
            tout = subprocess.check_output("lsusb | grep 1234:5678", shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            tout = None

        last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
        initial_search = False

        get_network_data(tout)

    if time_diff.seconds > 10:
        msg_count = 1

    if not initial_search and msg_count == 1:
        wait_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(600 - time_diff.seconds)
        message = wait_time.strftime('You may have to wait %-M minute(s), %-S second(s) before another check is done.')
        print('Could not retrieve data from page...')
        full_msg = '\n{0}'.format(message)
        inotify('My Balance', full_msg)
        #subprocess.call(['notify-send', 'iMonitor:Identify Phone', '\n{0}'.format(message)], preexec_fn=demote())
        msg_count += 1

try:
    initial_search = True
    last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
    msg_count = 1
    try:
        from pyudev.glib import MonitorObserver

    except ImportError:
        from pyudev.glib import GUDevMonitorObserver as MonitorObserver

    context = Context()
    monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)

    monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
    observer = MonitorObserver(monitor)

    observer.connect('device-added', identify_phone)
    monitor.start()

    glib.MainLoop().run()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nShutdown requested.\nExiting gracefully...')
    sys.exit(0)
```

However, the script runs as root and, having tried to change the uid and guid, I have not managed to get it to display desktop notifications to the logged in (normal) user. Any help would be appreciated.

PS:
OS - OpenSUSE 42.1 
KDE version - KDE Plasma 5.5.5

Comment: This question would be better answered on the [Linux site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need the script to run in KDE in which case you can simply copy or link the script into the `~/.kde/Autostart/` directory in KDE 4. In KDE 5 the directory has been moved to `~/.config/autostart`.

Comment: That folder doesn't exist

Comment: According to [KDE documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/index.html) the directory has been moved to `~/.config/autostart` in KDE5.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You can use cron job with `@reboot` modifier. It will run every time your system will boot up.

Comment: The cron job runs it as root